# Incorrect footer date in Meta 51

Tags: discussion, area-51

Can we use `DateTime.Today.Year` or something to get the current year rather then a static year in the footer of Area51:

[image]

Area51 is a beautiful site and `2011` just seems like ages ago, lets keep it standard across all the sites.

Comment: Ehm, wasn't the design actually done in 2011?

Comment: @MrLister Any single change forward a copyright date must be updated. It's pretty standard that the year is dynamic - we are web 2.0 now ;).

Comment: Has the site design or logo changed since then?

Comment: @JamesDonnelly I am quite certain we've had some changes over the past two years.  Aside from that, what happens when there is a change tomorrow?

Answer (score 2):

> It's pretty standard that the year is dynamic

### No.

Your idea is wrong. When you're claiming copyrights for things like this , the date represents since when you are claiming the copyright. So updating this every year would reset the count.

```
site design / logo 2011 (C)
```

In other words, we own the site design and logo since 2011.

You could ( I guess ) add a second date that could be updated. Something like this :

```
site design / logo 2011, 2013 (C)
```

**Maybe** the date is outdated since they last changed the design / logo one thing for sure, the date isn't and should not be dynamic.

Comment: Right when you are claiming the copyright, but did you read the footer?  It says site design / logo, the site design changes.  In fact, most companies are constantly redefining their site.  If you are constantly not updating and fixing bugs and changing things the competition will eat you alive.

Comment: @JonH I did. But did you read my answer ? The date must not be dynamic and the option your proposed will change the date every year **regardless of if changes were made or not**. This is wrong. It should be changed *when* the design is changed and not be changed automticly every 'x' time. Come back with the info of when the design / logo changed and proove they are outdated. Log a bug-request. But don't suggest stuff like `DateTime.Today.Year` since it would be and error in the copyright claim.

Comment: That okay I can agree with, but there should be some sort of indication of changes.  2011 is quite a bit back in time.  If your answer is what we are following then your answer is flawed considering all of the other stackexchange sites have the same 2013 date.

Comment: In fact, afaik, either option would be legally valid. (c) 2011, (c) 2013 and (c) 2011-2013 would make no difference.

Comment: @JonH 'm answering your question : `Can we use DateTime.Today.Year or something to get the current year rather then a static year in the footer of Area51`

Comment: I like Barts idea of begin date till today (C) 2011-2013...and moving forward 2011 - N.